# Magento 2 Image Selector in Widget CMS section

Tags: magento2

I've created a Magento 2 widget with an image chooser (among other things). When I use this widget in the CMS and add it straight to a page (Content > Pages > Edit Page > Insert Widget), the image chooser will show up correctly, and allow me to select or upload an image.

However, if I go into the Widgets section of the CMS (Content > Widgets > Add Widget), trying to use the same image chooser part of the Widget gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: MediabrowserUtility is not defined`.

In the searching that I've done, it seems that it's due to TinyMCE not being loaded on this page, but I can only find code references to fix it in Magento 1.

If that is the case, how would I get the right javascript file included on the Widgets page in the CMS?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

i have found this solution:
In the block of the Uploader (Ex: Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Uploader), the method prepareElementHtml(AbstractElement $element):

```
    $config = $this->_getData('config');
    $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg_images/index', ['target_element_id' => $element->getId(), 'type' => 'file']);

    $chooser = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(Button::class)
        ->setType('button')
        ->setClass('btn-chooser')
        ->setLabel($config['button']['open'])
        ->setOnClick('MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(\'' . $sourceUrl . '\', 0, 0, "MediaBrowser", {})')
        ->setDisabled($element->getReadonly());

    $input = $this->elementFactory->create("text", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
    $input->setId($element->getId());
    $input->setForm($element->getForm());
    $input->setClass("widget-option input-text admin__control-text");

    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $input->addClass('required-entry');
    }

    $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml() . $chooser->toHtml() . "<script>require(['mage/adminhtml/browser']);</script>");
    
    return $element;
```

Here is an [example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169455/magento-2-image-chooser-widget-problem).